# Including only specific rows with AutoBinNumeric() in Spotfire

Tags: histogram, spotfire, binning

Hi Spotfire professionals,

I am attempting to make a dynamic set of histograms for a large rectangular data frame (>2M rows) containing 34 unique columns and 69 unique row identifiers which preceed unique test data. The data table is of the following format, where "z" is the test data and a,b,c are unique identifiers:

```
##   a   b   c   ...   z
1    x1  x2  x3   ...  z1
2    x1  x2  x3   ...  z2 
3    y1  y2  y3   ...  z3
4    y1  y2  y3   ...  z4
```

What I want to be able to do is filter based on either x1 or y1 and have the histogram of the test data distribution be generated based on that selection. I cannot proceed with current options because different data selections can vary by many orders of magnitude.

I have already attempted `BinByEvenDistribution([z],200)` and manually forced the x-axis to be constrained to limits that make sense, but what I want is to make a "smarter" version of AutoBinNumeric() that calls on the filtered row value.

Because there are 69 unique row identifiers in my (proprietary) data set, with a variable amount of row IDs for other data sets using this template, I want something that will not require manual user inputs for anything other than selecting a unique row ID and I don't think creating new data tables is the most efficient solution here either.

In summary, can anyone out there provide me with guidance on how to make `AutoBinNumeric([z], 50)` call out only the z values that correspond with my filtered a,b, or c values without needing to add a ton of calculated columns?

Here is an example of my target output:

[image: Target Output]

Here is what I currently get using AutoBinNumeric([z], 5):

[image: AutoBinNumeric()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting a document property with a data function having the input be an expression of some count of items based on Filtering. Then use that document property in your expression `AutoBinNumeric([z], ${DocProperty})` that way as filters are changed your count() or uniquecount() will update then update your binby expression.

Comment: While that enables dynamic bin limits, it doesn't address the need for dynamic value filters for the category axis. This is my real issue. Perhaps I can take a similar approach, but I'll use a document property to define a data table that takes values from the source, depending on what is being filtered?

Comment: While your fix allows for setting a document property to modify the number of bins in my analysis, it wasn't the exact solution. Turns out, my problem was far more simple than this. There is an option under [Properties > Category Axis > Settings > Current filtering only]. 

Thank you for the guidance. I'm sure the use of document properties in function statements will serve me well in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Tyger's suggestion here is super helpful for enablement of dynamic options within the data function, but the exact solution to my question here came by using already built functionality in Spotfire.

If anyone runs across a similar issue, I was able to get my desired output by navigating through the histogram properties [Properties > Category Axis > Settings > Current filtering only].
[image: Current filtering]

Desired output:
[image: Desired output, with AutoBinNumeric() formula embedded]